# Python - Get the latest occurrence of a FreqDist Key from a series of FreqDist

Tags: python

I am aiming to generate a word dictionary, with the distinct FreqDist keys during the last 3 years but with the latest occurrence time.

I have generated a dictionary, with keys referring the date, and the values corresponding to the extracted FreqDist in that month.

```
{'20151': FreqDist({'physiotherapy': 11, 'claimant': 5, 'rehabilitation': 4, 'agent': 3, 'assessment': 3, 'client': 2, 'via': 1, 'jigsaw': 1, 'ticc': 1, 'accupuncture': 1, ...})}
{'20152': FreqDist({'physiotherapy': 12, 'rehabilitation': 7, 'assessment': 4, 'treatment': 4, 'claimant': 3, 'ltd': 3, 'appointment': 2, 'provider': 2, 'medical': 2, 'service': 2, ...})}

...

{'20184': FreqDist({'physiotherapy': 10, 'rehabilitation': 9, 'client': 8, 'claimant': 6, 'assessment': 5, 'ticc': 5, 'agent': 3, 'treatment': 3, 'symptom': 3, 'ltd': 3, ...})}
{'20185': FreqDist({'rehabilitation': 21, 'physiotherapy': 15, 'client': 9, 'assessment': 7, 'ticc': 6, 'agent': 6, 'detail': 5, 'ltd': 4, 'arrangement': 3, 'simply': 3, ...})}.
```

Then I would be able to get the distinct values from those FreqDist by

```
Rehab_Noun_list.append((FreqDist))
list(dict.fromkeys(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(Rehab_Noun_list))))
```

Wonder how would I report the latest occurrence of those distinct FreqDist keys given the month??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

ser = pd.Series([{'physiotherapy':10,'rehabilitation':9},
                 {'rehabilitation':21,'physiotherapy':15},
                 {'physiotherapy':12}])

count = defaultdict(int)

for d in ser:
    for key in d:
        count[key] += 1

print(count)
```

or:

```
ser.apply(pd.Series).count().to_dict()
Output: {'physiotherapy': 3, 'rehabilitation': 2}
```